# Does creating index on table containing million of rows causes any issue? Any danger exists for doing the same in live production DB?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, performance, indexing

Is there any dangers for creating index on a table containing millions of rows in live production db ? Does it causes any table locks or any performance issue while creating index? Is there any adverse effect it causes?

Comment: @NewBee I don't think it's a duplicate of that question. The answer for MySQL will not necessarily apply to Oracle.

Comment: @Error_2646 Oops sorry. Didn't notice the tag. I just read the question and nothing is mentioned there.

Answer (score 3):

Yes -- it will create locks and impact other users unless you use the `ONLINE` keyword in the `CREATE INDEX` command.  The `ONLINE` keyword will allow the index creation to happen without impacting DML operations on the table.  DDL on the table will be impacted, even with the `ONLINE` keyword (but DDL should not be happening on your table in production, usually).

If there is a lot of DML going on, it will slow down your index creation.

Also, you'll be using system resources to build the index (I/Os and sorts, etc).

Answer (score 1):

be careful, make sure you include the "online" option on the create index, otherwise it will put a table lock on the table, no one will be able to insert/update/delete the table while the index is creating, that would be bad

it will take resources to create the index, so that could affect users, you might want to do it off hours